# Change shell and execute commands within a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am facing a situation where I from within my script I have to execute a read-only-script which changes the shell and sets some environment variables. Now I need to access these environment variables from my script.

The situation is like script-A

```
#!/bin/csh -f
bash
#set some environment variables A,B,C
```

I do not have write access to script-A and it performs a lot of configurations which are necessary for my Script-B.

I have tried script-B with

```
#!/bin/csh -f
./script-A
echo $A
```

However since the shell has changed, I am unable to access $A. Is there some work around such that I can do this.

Ideally the commands in my script-B has to be run in the new environment of script-A. While interacting manually, this is fine as I can first execute script-A and then execute the required commands. However, I have to automate the whole process.

Comment: This can't be the actual `script-A`; as it stands, it would give you an interactive Bash that awaits orders.

Comment: I seem to have made some mistake abt Script-A. As it is currently it wouldn't work either. But the philosophy of the Q remains the same. There is a script that changes the shell and makes some configurations in that shell (It stays interactive). I need to execute some commands in that shell

Comment: Then you should `source` the other file instead of executing it: `source script-A`.

Comment: This is what I tried: In script-B I did source script-A. However the commands after it in the script are not getting executed.

Comment: Then you'll really have to show at least part of the scripts so we have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

If script-A is a csh script, then

```
source script-A
```

This works even if script-A contains exit statements:

```
$ cat x.csh 
#!/bin/csh

source y.csh
echo $A - $B

cat y.csh 
#!/bin/csh

set A=10
set B=20
exit 1
set B=30

$ ./x.csh 
10 - 20
```

If script-A is in another shell, you need to rewrite script-B to match that shell

Oh, and by the way, [DITCH CSH](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt) if at all possible:

Comment: This would work if every sub-process executed the same command interpreter, but this doesn't appear to be the case. You cannot source a bash script from a csh one.

Comment: But he has the #!/bin/csh at the top of both script-A and script-B in his question... Even if script A internally calls bash, this should not break source.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your own script in the same shell language as the one you need to execute so that you can execute it with the shell's `source` command.